# owl carousel change click on custom div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I have a simple owl-carousel.

**HTML**

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">This is item one </div>
  <div class="item"> This is item two</div>
  <div class="item">this is item three</div>
  <div class="item">this is item four</div>
</div>

<ul class="sl-nav">
  <li>one </li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>  
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
   items: 1,
   loop:true,
   nav:true,
   margin: 10
})
```

Included:

- owl.carousel.js
- owl.carousel.min.css

How to force the carousel scroll to the clicked on nav item?